# How to write the following code using map, filter and lambda

Tags: python, lambda, list-comprehension

```
[(x, y) for x in range(5) if x % 2 == 0 for y in range(5) if y % 2 == 1]
```

I know list comprehensions are more concise, just curious to know how to use map, filter and lambda here.

Thanks!

Comment: Read http://www.python-course.eu/lambda.php

Comment: Could you tell us what your code is trying to do?

Comment: @ whackamadoodle3000 its trying to create a list of tuples of even and odd numbers from 0 to 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem does not lend itself to mapping very easily. It is basically just a filtering problem of the product of two lists. Thus, using the `product` function from `itertools` the same functionality could be achieved as:

```
from itertools import product
list(filter(lambda pair: pair[0]%2 == 0 and pair[1]%2 == 1, product(range(5), repeat=2)))
```

The enclosing `list` is because in Python 3, the `filter` function returns an iterable `filter object`.